# Replacing multiple variables for one object?

Tags: java, oop, object

**My job was to:**

> Revise the Node class to a generic one so that it can handle folders and files in a file system shown below.

**And also:**

> First, you need to modify the Node class so that both 'size' and 'name' will be replaced by one object.

Now, I did the first part where we change the class to use generic types. I'm stuck at second problem. I don't know how to pass single object instead of 2 variables and then do bunch of computation within it.

***How would I substitute multiple variables for single object here?*** I've been trying to change types and move things around but my code keeps failing as soon as I remove those 2 variables.

**Code:**

```
class Node<T>
   {
   public String name;
   public int size;
   public Node<T> leftChild;
   public Node<T> rightChild;

   public void displayNode()
      {
      System.out.print('{');
      System.out.print(name);
      System.out.print(", ");
      System.out.print(size);
      System.out.print("} ");
      }
   }  // end class Node
```

Comment: I don't see any iData and dData there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redesign it like this:

```
class Node<T> {
    public T data;
    public Node<T> leftChild;
    public Node<T> rightChild;

    public void displayNode() {
        System.out.print('{');
        System.out.print(data.toString());
        System.out.print("} ");
   }
   . . .
}
```

**EDIT** One way to rewrite your `find` method is for it to find a particular `T` value:

```
public Node<T> find(Comparable<T> target) {
    Node<T> current = root;
    int comp = target.compareTo(current.data);
    while (comp != 0) {
        if (comp < 0)
            current = current.leftChild;
        else
            current = current.rightChild;
        if(current == null)
            return null;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but later in program I need to access variables name and size from different class and methods to do some sort of comparison for my binary tree. How would I pull those values out of this object?

Comment: @HelpNeeder - Without seeing your code, it's hard to say exactly. As a general rule, your comparison methods need to be made generic as well. Alternatively, you can declare your type parameter to be `T extends Comparable<T>`

Comment: I added some more code if you like to review it. And I agree with your note.

Comment: @HelpNeeder - I wrote an updated `find` method. If you declared the generic type for the class to be `T extends Comparable<T>`, then the argument to `find` could be of type `T` instead of `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: This looks interesting. Let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a `Custom Data Class`. That class will wrap your required variables as attribute.

For e.g., in your case: -

```
public class MyData {
    private String name;  // Your data are enclosed in the data object MyData
    private int size;

    /** Constructors **/
    /** Getters and Setters **/
}
```

Now, wherever, you are using those variables, use an instance of this class. And your generic class would be changed as per @TedHopp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245055/1679863).

And your `Node` class will be instantiated like this: -

```
Node<MyData> node = new Node<MyData>();
```

So, your `T` now becomes `MyData`. So, if you want to access `size` and `name`, you would have to do it like this: -

```
node.getMyData().getSize();
node.getMyData().getName();
```

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea, but there's nothing in my instructions to create additional class.

Comment: @HelpNeeder.. Some times, things are not written in instruction explicitly. You have to infer them out of it. Your class being made `generic` and wrapping your variables in `single object`, means you need another class. And this is the appropriate way.